# Comment Flag Dialog Bugfix

Tags: script, style, userstyle

### About

Fixes issues with Comment Flag dialog appearing in the upper-left corner of the window.

#### Download

<kbd>[Download](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/raw/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css)</kbd> or view the <kbd>[source code](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/blob/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css)</kbd>

#### Platform

Tested on Waterfox 56. Only designed for Firefox-compatible browsers.

### Code

This userstyle requires the [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) add-on.

Found an issue? Send me a [bug report](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/issues/new?template=bug_report.md) on Github.